# Reading from the stream has failed - MySqlException

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database-connection, connection-string

I'm trying to open a connection to a MySql database using the following code piece:

```
string connectionString = "Server=ip_number;Database=database_name;Uid=uid;Password=password";
MySqlConnection connection;
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

And here is the exception I get:

[image]

I'm using the latest mysql connector ([downloaded from here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)). What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you checked that the connection string is valid? In your code you have database_name, uid and password. Have you omitted the actual values, are these the values needed to access the database?

Comment: Yes they are the actual values. I can connect to db via phpMyAdmin using the values from connection string. I replaced them due to security reasons.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. What's even more obscure is the fact that my application was working for months without any problems. Without changing anything, a few days ago it started giving me this error and it's been like this ever since...

Comment: My case was about network permissions. Talk to your network admin after trying to connect to your db ip and port via telnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you try this:

Connection to server:

```
string connectionString= "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=uid;password=1234"
```

Use the "MySqL-Methodes" to INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT... like:

```
    public string pathselectDB = "select *from try.data;";
    public string pathinsertDB = "INSERT INTO `try`.`data`";

        string constrnig = pathtoDB;
        string Query = pathinsertDB +"(`value1`, `value2`) values('"2"','3',');";



        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constrnig);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
```

this is  just an example... I hope this solved your problem.

You can set your username and password in the MySql-Editor! if you need help there just set a commend under this.

Comment: This answer doesn't tell me what I'm doing wrong. I tried adding the port to the connection string but nothing changes.

Comment: I think your connection string is the problem. May you try it like in my answer given. You already got a MySql-Database isn´t so? Have you installed the MySql-Editor? there a many options to connect the programm with the Database. In the following link you can check out all methodes for the Sql-Database:  [link](http://www.php-kurs.com/mysql-select-anweisung.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1: If SSL is not required. Since it is caused by SSL, we can turn off SSL by appending "SslMode=None" to the connection string.

Solution 2: If SSL is required, server identity is important and needs to be verified. The server needs a internet connection to do the cert verification. Please note the crypto API doesn't update CTL for every process. The CTL is maintained at operating system level. Once you connect the server to internet and make an SSL database connection to the server, the CTL will be updated automatically. Then you may disconnect the internet connection. Note again the CTL has its expiration date and after that the Windows needs to update it again. This will occur probably after several months.

Solution 3: If SSL is required but the server identity is not important. Typically SSL is only used to encrypt the network transport in this case. We can turn off CTL update:

- Press Win+R to open the "Run" dialog Type "gpedit.msc" (without
  quotes) and press Enter In the "Local Group Policy Editor", expand
  "Computer Configuration", expand "Administrative Templates", expand
  "System", expand "Internet Communication Management", and then click
  "Internet Communication settings". In the details panel, double-click
  "Turn off Automatic Root Certificates Update", click **Enabled**,
  then click OK. This change will be effective immediately without
  restart.

https://blog.csdn.net/fancyf/article/details/78295964 Clearly explains the root cause and solution.

Comment: I asked the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/58237785/11035837 in relation to your answer and the bizarre behavior of my error that clears out on a refresh.